# Oracle PL/SQL Check if Parameter Has Special Characters

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Wondering if there's a way to check if a parameter has any special characters and also spaces. Spaces I am assuming I'll just use `LIKE '% %'` to do this. Apologies if this is a dumb question, but I am currently a student with barely any background experience in Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: Describe what you call a *special character*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `regexp_like()`:

```
regexp_like(mycol, '\W')
```

`'\W'` stands for any character *other than* a digit, an alphabetic character or an underscore (`_`). If any character in the string matches on this pattern, the condition succeeds.